# Why does do similar queries return different email results in Gmail search?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Why does searching in Gmail for "from:(uber@uber.com AND eats) OR ubereats@uber.com OR (noreply@uber.com AND eats)" return results that match "from:(noreply@uber.com AND -eats)" but searching for "from:(noreply@uber.com AND eats)" alone does not?

Let's break it down to math:
Search "(A AND B) OR C OR (D AND B)" includes "D AND NOT B"
Search "D AND NOT B" obviously includes "D AND NOT B"
Search "A AND B" does not include "D AND NOT B"
Search "C" does not include "D AND NOT B"
Search "D AND B" does not include "D AND NOT B"

Why? What am I missing from Gmail logic that is so counterintuitive for a power user?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. AND is not a Gmail search operator Ref. [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)